# Setting the Build Directory of an Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, build-process, directory

So far, no matter what I try, Xcode dumps my project's products in a subfolder of the project directory.  I've tried each setting under Build Locations, but it doesn't seem to work.  If I try `Users/MyName/svn/trunk`, it'll end up in the project folder `.../MyProject/Users/MyName...`.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would adding a preceding `/` before your build path fix it? (eg: `/Users/...` instead of `Users/...` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try going to:

Project -> Edit Project Settings -> General -> Place Build Products In: Custom Location.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to set this depending on the build configuration?  Ideally, I'd like it only to move to the SVN trunk if I compile it under Release.